# Someone who favors both sides of a mutually exclusive argument is called or said to be _______?

Tags: adjectives

Someone who favors both sides of an argument....both solutions which are mutually exclusive are said to be ______?

Comment: The use of *favour* here is unusual. You might say that you "heap favour" on both sides for being well-argued, but normally when you're asked "Which side do you *favour*?" it means, "Which side do you like best"? You can say one or the other, or neither, but you can't say both. (But you could like or understand both.)

Comment: @JasonBassford yes, *in a logical sense*, but not everyone is logical. I've been at not one but several meetings where a person has voted "for" a proposal and also voted "against" it. And there are - dare I say it - diplomats who may confide their support to *each* of two warring sides. I think "favour" is therefore perfectly sensible to use in this situation. :-)

Answer (score 4):

He is said to be **on the fence**, or he is said to be sitting on the fence

> **sit on the fence**
>   Avoid making a decision or choice.

[oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sit_on_the_fence)

Answer (score 3):

I think the best fit would be 'ambivalent'. That can cover both uncertainty and having contradictory feelings.

Comment: Having mixed feelings or contradictory ideas about something or someone - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ambivalent

Answer (score 2):

You could say they *are riding two horses at once*.

> **ride two horses at once**.
>   To do (or attempt to do) two or more things simultaneously, often when those things conflict or are at odds with one another. *The prime minister is clearly riding two horses at once—trying to fulfill his promises to the public to lower taxes, while also trying to find the money to help the country's struggling economy. When I was a younger actor, I was constantly riding two horses at once, taking on as many roles as I could—even if they overlapped.*. 
>   [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc,](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ride+two+horses+at+once) all rights reserved.

Answer (score 1):

**uncommitted**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fence-sitter)

adjective

> not committed, especially not pledged or bound to a specific cause, candidate, or course of action

As in:

> Someone who favors both sides of an argument....both solutions which
>   are mutually exclusive are said to be **uncommitted**.

Answer (score 0):

If they supported each side in a deceitful way, then they would be described as

> **[two-faced](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/two-faced)**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>   Insincere and deceitful.
>
> *‘But on this matter of trade, conference, Europe is two-faced: demanding market opening from the poor, but practising protectionism
>   to defend their own special interests.’*

In similar vein, you could use [duplicitous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/duplicitous), meaning "deceitful".

The duality implicit in the root of both words (*duplicitous* and *two-faced*) is especially appropriate to the scenario described in the question. Of the two expressions, I think *two-faced* is the more pointed and powerful epithet.

Answer (score 0):

**Neutral**

> Not supporting either side in a disagreement, argument or conflict; impartial

**Undecided**

> Not having made a decision

**Unbiased**

> impartial or without bias or prejudice

**Impartial**

> Treating all rivals or disputants equally